# My terminal crashes Ubuntu upon opening

Tags: 20.04, gnome-terminal, crash

I finally got through my issues here:

[I cannot open the terminal and I cannot use any applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1309726/i-cannot-open-the-terinal-and-i-cannot-use-any-applications/1309728#1309728)

After that was resolved, I tried to open a terminal. When it opens, everything but the terminal window goes black. The screen flashes on and off three times, and then Ubuntu crashes saying "something went wrong and Ubuntu couldn't recover" and prompts me to log out. I have searched for a solution to no avail

edit: I'm discovering that ANY application I try to open crashes the system

Comment: Have you changed the default version of python3?   What do you get with `python3 -V; python -V`   Did you make any changes (added packages, additional drivers) in the last session before you had problems?

Comment: This is an unusual number of issues to have with a fresh installation. Could you share some details about what kind of hardware you're running? You had mentioned in the previous question that you had an AMD video card that has known issues. Which one is it? What kind of processor are you using? This might help someone offer some specific suggestions.